# How netty's html-style user guide doc generated?

Tags: html, markdown, netty, doc, generated

I am reading [The Netty Project 3.x User Guide](http://static.netty.io/3.5/guide/) and wondering how the doc generated, markdown or something else?

Comment: By the looks of it not with lots of care :)

Answer (score 1):

It used to use a tool developed by Trustin [ApiViz](http://code.google.com/p/apiviz/)

Comment: Thanks! It looks like ApiViz is used to generate advanced javadoc with UML-like diagrams, but how the page [The Netty Project 3.x User Guide](http://static.netty.io/3.5/guide/) is generated?